# Funcion para borrar caché automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, cache

Me gustaría crear un boton o alguna meta tag para que mi página borre la caché automaticamente cuando refresque.
He probado con algo así pero no funciona

```html
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Tambien he probado hacerlo en php y tampoco funciona

```html
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
  header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Fecha en el pasado
?>
```

Comment: En php debiera ser `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");` (no-cache es como para IE6. no-store es para HTTP 1.1) y `header("Expires: 0");` que afecta más bien a los proxies. Puedes omitir el pragma que es obsoleto

Comment: No funciona en ningun caso. El php deberia de ir en algun sitio en especial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me autorespondo:

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es versionar los archivos css/js de la siguiente forma:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css?n=1">
```

Esto obliga al navegador a ver que es una nueva version del css y leer todo el archivo otra vez

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer tanto como en PHP como en el HTML.

#### Desde PHP

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

#### Desde HTML

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Answer (score 1):

yo tenia problemas con la cache cuando queria publicar un pdf y cambiaba el valor el pdf me mostraba el saldo anterior y lo que hice fue (en php).

asi estaba llamando el pdf: `<embed id="ticket"  name="embed_content" src="www.xxxxxx.com/tikects/E-TICKETw123456.pdf" />`, le agrege lo siguiente...

1. primero cree numeros random y lo guarde en una variable: `$rann = rand(22,99999);`
2. luego agrege una variable GET llamado 't' y le agrege el valor aleatorio para que el navegador no busque el mismo link ya almacenado en cache asi.. `<embed id="ticket"  name="embed_content" src="www.xxxxxx.com/tikects/E-TICKETw123456.pdf?t=<?php echo $rann?>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function random_version (){
$hash =  base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30));
$v = $hash.'='.uniqid();
return $v;
}
```

Y lo puedes usar de la siguiente forma:

```
caja/js/func_portero_ap.js?'.random_version()
```

Cabe recalcar que estoy haciendo patron MVC pero puedes implementar en html de la siguiente forma:

```
<script src="algo.js?<?php echo random_version();?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="algo.css?<?php echo random_version();?>">
```