# borrar valores del input file en php variable $_file

Tags: php, html, sql, archivo

Hola grupo a ver si me pueden ayudar, tengo este problema, tengo un formulario en `PHP` muy sencillo solo tengo el `input type="file"` y carga el archivo a la base de datos, pero si recargo la pagina vuelve y me carga los mismos datos, como puedo hacer para que al recargar la pagina no tenga problema con que vuelva hacer todo el mismo proceso, necesito como borrar el cache o eliminar los valores del  `input type="file"` o de `$_files`, muchas gracias agrego el código

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "../php/conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();

    $tamanoTabla="450px";

    if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
        $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

        while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ","))
        {
            //si la linea es igual a 1 no guardamos por que serian los títulos de la hoja del excel.
            $numero = count($data);
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO archivoHabilitacionRenta values ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[0]-$data[1]')");
        }

    }else{
        $tamanoTabla="0px";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

    ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Habilitación Articulos</title>
                <?php
                 ##Agrego las extenciones y librerias
                 require '../view/ext.html';
                ?>  
            </head>
        <body>
        <?php include("../view/Menu.php");?>
        <?php require("../view/barra.html");?>

         <?php $sql="select distinct t2.razonSocial,t2.nit,t2.cardCode from AlmacenesRenta  t1
                        left join clientes t2
                        on t1.nit=t2.nit";

          $ResultadoClientes =sqlsrv_query($conexion,$sql); ?>
          <div class="container">
          <br>
          <br>

          <form action="ReglasHabilitacionArticulosRenta.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
              <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />  <br /> 
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
          </form>
?>
```

Comment: Si de cache se trata ya hay un hilo con el mismo explicado detalladamente [Justo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164966/funcion-para-borrar-cach%C3%A9-automaticamente) Pido disculpas de antemano por ponerlo como respuesta, pero aun no tengo el privilegio para comentar :(

Comment: Lo probe con ese y no :(, pero gracias

Comment: Y si tratas de validar de que este vació al momento de que la pagina cargue y si no lo esta le asigne un valor vació.

Comment: Y si antes de guardar, hacer una consulta contra esa tabla para saber si hay valores,  y en caso que no los haya haces el insert into ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que después de que hagas la inserción a la base de datos deberías aplicar un `header('location:_tupagina.php_');` luego de que el ciclo while termine. así no reenviará los datos del formulario. Avísanos como te va

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, lo intente pero no, cuando actualiza con el comando header('location:_tupagina.php_'); hace nuevamente la insercion :(

Comment: Intenta quitarle la condicional de la sesión, puede ser eso también

Comment: En su defecto puedes hacer lo siguiente `if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){header('location:login.php');}`

Comment: Tambien deberias usar la función `array_key_exists` te dejare la documentación para que la uses. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php